# Laravel query hasMany where rows with custom values

Tags: laravel, select, has-many

I have following tables in my DB:

```
TABLE_PRODUCTS
id
name

TABLE_VARIANTS
id
product_id
sku

TABLE_VARIANTS_PROPERTIES
id
variant_id
property_value_id
```

I'm trying to build query for filtering products. Let's say I want to show only that products which have variants with property_value_id=1 and property_value_id=2

Relations: PRODUCTS -> hasMany -> VARIANTS -> hasMany -> VARIANTS_PROPERTIES.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:

I used Alexandr Peters answer. Here is my code:

```
$query->whereHas('variants.properties.propertiesValues', function ($query) use ($variants) {
        $query->whereIn('value', $variants);
    });
```

To be more specific I have one more table in my query which I didn't specify before. This query works but not as expected. What I want to do is:
Get all PRODUCTS which have PRODUCTS_VARIANTS which have PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_PROPERTIES which have PRODUCTS_PROPERTIES_VALUES as active filter (VARIANTS). I know all variants - I'm using cartesian product for this.
So for example I need to get all products which have variants which have all values from variant in filter. This query works only if there are variants only with 1 value. How can I solve this? I'm trying with foreach($variants as ...) but no luck. Still not working 100% as expected.

TABLES:

```
TABLE_PRODUCTS
id
name

TABLE_PRODUCTS_VARIANTS 
id
product_id
sku

TABLE_PRODUCTS_VARIANTS_PROPERTIES
id
variant_id
property_value_id

TABLE_PRODUCTS_PROPERTIES_VALUES
id
value
```

All possible variants from active filter are in nested array for example I have active filter with color BLACK and RED and size filter XS:

```
[
0 => [
    0 => Black
    1 => XS
  ]
1 => [
    0 => Red
    1 => XS
  ]
]
```

I need to check values from VARIANTS array in last table TABLE_PRODUCTS_PROPERTIES_VALUES in column value. But it needs to have both values (Black & XS)

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE - SOLVED

Ok I finally solved it. Here is my code:

```
$query->whereHas('variants', function ($query) use ($variants) {
        $i = 1;
        foreach($variants as $variant)
        {
            if($i == 1) {
                $query->whereHas('properties', function($query) use ($variant) {
                    $query->whereHas('propertiesValues', function($query) use ($variant) {
                        $query->whereIn('value', $variant);
                    });
                }, '=', count($variant));
            } else {
                $query->orWhereHas('properties', function($query) use ($variant) {
                    $query->whereHas('propertiesValues', function($query) use ($variant) {
                        $query->whereIn('value', $variant);
                    });
                }, '=', count($variant));
            }

            $i++;
        }
    });
```

Any ideas how to make it less complicated? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested **has** or **whereHas** statements may also be constructed using "dot" notation. For example, you may retrieve all posts that have at least one comment and vote. So if you want to query nested variants_properties from products you have to put it with dots '**relation1.relation2**' in whereHas

```
$ids = [1,2];
$products = Product::whereHas('variants.variants_properties', function ($query) use ($ids) {
    $query->whereIn('property_value_id', $ids);
})->get();
```

Comment: This is not working because property_variant is not JOINED and you are asking whereIn

Comment: You don't need to join table because whereHas query relationships. This is  100% working code I use for filtering attributes or category of the product which has Many-to-many relations

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but where do you use whereHas to table TABLE_VARIANTS_PROPERTIES ? You are just using whereHas to TABLE_VARIANTS. Or is whereIn generating whereHas in mysql query?

Comment: Variants is not a table. ii is many-to-many relation. I have update my answer to show that you can you relationships.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working for me. Honestly I don't understand your answer with many-to-many relation. Maybe it's not working because I have much more relations in my query but I just wanted to write it here in simple way...

Comment: Yes this is working but still one issue. Imagine in filter you choose colors BLACK and RED and in sizes XS. Then you have 2 variants: BLACK-XS and RED-XS.
How can I solve this. I have all possible variants from active filters I'm just struggling with query...

Comment: you can make it with foreach loop and check if you filter has single & multiple values. So you can use where() or whereIn() for choosing exact products from DB.

Comment: @AlexandrPeters thank you for your answer. This is the way I'm trying whole day but still not working as expected. I updated my question. I would really really appreciate any help....